Можно ли добавлять в свою сборку библиотеки-оболочки над OpenGL?
Сейчас активно учу C#, задался вопросом.
Вот я хочу писать приложения с использованием OpenGL,но вдруг выясняю, что OpenGL на шарпе можно использовать только через посредника в виде оболочки-библиотеки (например, OpenTK или TAO и т. п.).
Значит, чтобы поставлять моё приложение конечным пользователям, у них тоже должна быть эта библиотека, но заставлять пользователя отдельно скачивать и как-то заставлять мою сборку ссылаться на эти библиотеки-оболочки над OpenGL как-то не очень.
Вместе с тем сколько я не искал, я не понимаю, могу ли я в свою сборку эти оболочки "запихнуть" — а легально ли это и не засудят ли меня?

"OpenGL на шарпе можно использовать только через посредника в виде оболочки-библиотеки " - это не соответствует действительности. Можно дергать все функции напрямую посредством pinvoke. "легально ли это" - это вам надо куда-нибудь на форум юристов.

понятно, спасибо за ответ, странно, впервые про pinvoke слышу. Хорошо, что это так, ато я уже начал думать, что надо на плюсы переходить, а я рихтера уже наполовину прочитал, было бы обидно.

Ну если действительно хотите плотно занятся opengl, то однозначно стоит переходить на плюсы...

Разве есть какая-то функциональность OpenGL , которую c# не может использовать?

Наверное нет, однако пытаться писать достаточно низкоуровневый код с явным управлением памятью и прочими ресурсами на C#, то и дело дергая код на С, - откровенная перверсия.

Да, печально. Я конечно знал об этом с самого начала, но не думал, чтоэто окажется серьезной проблемой, сейчас подробно об этом узнал.  Я уже начал читать C++ Primer , а рихтера отправил в долгий ящик(она интересная, когда-нибудь дочитаю).  Спасибо за ответ!

Нашёл ответ:

Во-первых, оболочка не обязательно нужна — есть Pinvoke (спасибо @user7860670);
Во-вторых, чтобы узнать, можно ли включать в свою сборку библиотеки сторонних вендоров, нужно найти их "политику" и прочитать — там есть условия использования.

